# Get the Termset with Javascript and nothing return

Tags: javascript, jsom, taxonomy

We are working on a SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm. I am trying to return the termset object with ID 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx'. Here is my script. I add a content editor webpart and insert following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){       
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.Runtime.js', 'SP.Runtime', function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.Taxonomy.js', 'SP.Taxonomy', loadTerms)
        });
    });
});

function loadTerms(){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.taxonomy.js', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', function () {   
        var termId = 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx';   
        console.log(termId);
        getTerm(termId,printTermInfo,printError);
    });
}


function printTermInfo(term)
{
    console.log(String.format('Name: {0}',term.get_name()));
    console.log('success');
}

function printError(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
    console.log('fail');
}
</script>
```

The problem is it return nothing. No error no console log is found. In the F12 tool I can see runtime.js and taxonomy.js is returned with http 200. I think they are loading correctly. What could be the problem?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I feel there is something missing in your code. In my coding practice I used to connect to metadata service, get term sets and then term..

Comment: Why are you calling `SP.Taxonomy.js` twice? Could you share your `getTerm` code?

Comment: getTerm is a function within SP.Taxonomy.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently worked with the same requirement, so here i am sharing my solution which i used to get the TermSet object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(LoadAllTerms, 'SP.Taxonomy.js');
});

//loads all existing navigation terms
function LoadAllTerms() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAllNavigationTerms);
}

//gets all existing navigation terms
function getAllNavigationTerms() {
    var metaDataServiceName = “” Your Managed MetaData Service Name”;
    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function () {
                termContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(termContext); //Current Taxonomy Session
                var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores(); //Term Stores                        
                termStore = termStores.getByName(metaDataServiceName); //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.                       
                navigationTermSet = termStore.getTermSet("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX"); //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
               // navigationTermSet is your termset object
           });
        });
    });
}
```

The above code is working fine for me.

Let me know if you need some more assist.

Answer (score 3):

I have used below function to get terms from the term set. You can inspire from it.

First connect to SharePoint Taxonomy session, get hold hold of Default Term Store.

```
function customGetTerm() {

    var termSetName = "Your Term Set Name",
    locale = 1033,
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
    taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext),
    termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore(),
    termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termSetName, locale),
    termSet = termSets.getByName(termSetName),
    terms = termSet.getAllTerms(),

    term = terms.getByName("Term Name"),
    childTerms = term.get_terms();

    clientContext.load(childTerms); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function onSuccess() {
        var enumerator = childTerms.getEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var spTerm = enumerator.get_current();

        }

    }, function onFailure(args) {
        alert('Error');
    });
}
```